# Regexp- replace specific line break in String

Tags: java, regex, regexp-replace

I am seeking for a **regexp** that finds a specific line break `\n` from a long String.

The specific `\n` is the one **before a line that do not contains a specific char**: **'#'**

As example:

> This tis a fine #line1\nThis tis another fine #line2\nThis_belongs_to abobe line\nThis tis still is OK #line4

that represents the text:

```
this tis a fine #line1
this tis another fine #line2
this_belongs_to abobe line
this tis still is OK #line4
```

here the `\n` to be removed in the one after #line2, **resulting** in the text:

```
this tis a fine #line1
this tis another fine #line2this_belongs_to abobe line
this tis still is OK #line4
```

I came up with a regexp like: `\n^(?m)(?!.*#).*$` that is close, but I can't figure out how to build the right one that allows me to match and remove only the right line break and preserve the remaining text/String.

Perhaps there is a better way than using regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```java
text = text.replaceAll("\\R(?!.*#)", "");
text = text.replaceAll("(?m)\\R(?=[^\n#]+$)", "");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/m2r5Rc/2) / [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/m2r5Rc/1). *Details*:

- `(?m)` - `Pattern.MULTILINE` embedded flag option to make `$` in this pattern match end of a line, not the end of the whole string
- `\R` - any line break sequence
- `(?!.*#)` - a negative lookahead that matches a location not immediately followed with any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then a `#` char
- `(?=[^\n#]+$)` - a positive lookahead that requires one or more chars (replace `+` with `*` to match an empty line, too) other than an LF and `#` up to an end of a line.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/UxSq5v) online:

```java
String s_lf = "this tis a fine #line1\nthis tis another fine #line2\nthis_belongs_to abobe line\nthis tis still is OK #line4";
String s_crlf = "this tis a fine #line1\r\nthis tis another fine #line2\r\nthis_belongs_to abobe line\r\nthis tis still is OK #line4";
 
System.out.println(s_lf.replaceAll("\\R(?!.*#)", "")); 
System.out.println(s_crlf.replaceAll("\\R(?!.*#)", ""));
 
System.out.println(s_lf.replaceAll("(?m)\\R(?=[^\n#]+$)", "")); 
System.out.println(s_crlf.replaceAll("(?m)\\R(?=[^\n#]+$)", ""));
```

All test cases - with strings having CRLF and LF line endings - result in

```
this tis a fine #line1
this tis another fine #line2this_belongs_to abobe line
this tis still is OK #line4
```